# In LaTeX not able to add space (i.e. use \vspace{length}) in multicolumn (i.e. in \begin{multicols} environment)

Tags: latex

I am trying to add vertical space in first column but after writing \vspace{10cm}, still not getting the required result.
[Image of required result can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02E0d.png).
If there is some problem in code (Code is attached), then please correct. Otherwise you can also suggest other method.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \vspace{10cm}
            \begin{flushleft}
                Date:
                \\ Place
            \end{flushleft}
            
            \columnbreak
            Examiners   \\
            \begin{flushright}
                
                \par
                1.\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw [thick,densely dashed={dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (7,0);
                \end{tikzpicture}
                \par
                2.\begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw [thick,densely dashed={dash pattern=on 3pt off 2pt}] (0,0) -- (7,0);
                \end{tikzpicture}
            \end{flushright}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work if the `\vspace` is not the first thing in the column. You could add something invisible like `\mbox{}` before it.

Off-topic:

- using tikz for the doted lines feels a bit overkill, you could use `\dotfill` instead (this would also avoid the overfull box warnings)
- you shouldn't abuse `\\` for line breaks, this causes many underfull box warnings. Just leave an empty line instead to start a new paragraph

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \mbox{}
        \vspace{10cm}
        \begin{flushleft}
            Date:
            
            Place
        \end{flushleft}
        
        \columnbreak
        
        Examiners   
        
        \begin{flushright}
            \par
            1.\dotfill
            \par
            2.\dotfill
        \end{flushright}
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It will be okay for dotted line, but is there any way for getting flexible dashed line and not dotted line ?

Comment: @VinayFaria Have a look at the `dashrule` package. If you need tikz also for other things in your document, using it won't be any disadvantage, but if not, it will make compiling considerably slower, so alternatives might be easier

Comment: Great answer, great @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz ! It solved a problem I'm currently facing.

Comment: @HiltonFernandes Nice to hear you could solve your problem! Thanks for the feedback!